# Scroll only one part of horizontal row keeping the other fixed

Tags: css, angularjs

> html

```
<div class="xxx">
    <div class="xyz" ng-repeat="item in formList">
        <div ng-show="formList.indexOf(app)!= -1" class="added-item">
            <img class="col-md-6 added-item-icon" ng-src="app.iconFile"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="abc" ng-hide="formList.length>20">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="addItem()">
            Add<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> css

```
.xxx {
    width:500px;
    height: 80px;        
}
.added-item-icon, .abc {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I'm not good in css, and have only very basic knowledge
I am trying to add some list of items in a horizontal tab of height 80 and width 500 pixels, also an add app button too
As per the code, the add app button disappear when we add the 20th app

what I need to do is, lets say the xxx div(horizontal div) can have 5 items, after which overflow occurs
I want to set the overflow horizontal, not vertical
also at that stage(when 5 items are added), I want to fix the add app button at the very right of the division xxx, and the scroll due to overflow should not affect that button, it should be fixed there

we doesn't need to care more about the size of the item icons or add button, 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll want to look into using **flexbox**.  To get this working, all you really need to do is add `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to your container, and then `overflow-y: auto` to the section you want to scroll.

Heres a [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/UMxiUPTs2jHhRRm0?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1) demonstrating it.